# How to create a view to display only child nodes of a parent term?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to create a view which displays only the child nodes of selected taxonomy term?

I have something like this

```
-Fruit
--Apple
---Green
---Red
```

and when I click on fruit (taxonomy/tem/1), I want to display only nodes with term apple, green, red. Now It is displaying nodes from fruit, too, but I dont want it. I have some nodes with term fruit but I dont want to display it when I click on fruit.. only nodes from fruit children terms.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that this way is possible,but a situation near to this is possible as:-
1. While creating a view,we have a field known as "filter criteria" field,in that add --**Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth) (or Unknown) **

1. Go into the settings of this field**strong text** and choose depth of the field.**
2. Here **Depth** means-The depth will match nodes tagged with terms in the hierarchy. For example, if you have the term "fruit" and a child term "apple", with a depth of 1 (or higher) then filtering for the term "fruit" will get nodes that are tagged with "apple" as well as "fruit". If negative, the reverse is true; searching for "apple" will also pick up nodes tagged with "fruit" if depth is -1 (or lower).**
3. this can be of help if u don't mark any node with the **fruit** tag,but mark all nodes with the **some children tags of fruit**.

Answer (score 1):

The Views module has a taxonomy_term View which can be used. You need to edit the View so that under the Arguments -> Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth) -> change the depth depending on your requirement. If you want to exclude the parent item, you can do this by adding a filter to exclude the parent term.

I found a link as well that might help:
[Display terms only if associated with a node](https://drupal.org/node/2010018)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is a problem that I cant pass parent term id to filter from url. When I use filter "taxonomy term: term id" and set operator to "is not equal to=1" everything look ok, but I dont know how to add term id as value for all terms.. I tried to use "%" but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Add 
RELATIONSHIPS  -> Taxonomy term: Parent term

**do not forget to check checkbox -> Require this relationship**